# netbeans markup of comment

Tags: netbeans, autocomplete, comments

I wonder if it is possible to edit the way the NetBeans autocomplete markup of comment.

wanted to change:

```
/*
 * comment
 */
```

to:

```
/*
* comment
*/
```

is it possible?

Comment: Why would you want it? don't you like the standard Indentation of code?

Comment: I do not like, it is misaligned, got used to doing manually and would like to change ... Anyone know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really possible to do exactly what you want. The best thing I found is :

> Tools -> Options -> Editor
>
> Select **Java** and **Comment**

Then unckeck `Add Leading Star`

Now when you type : `/**`, it will be expanded as :

```
/**

*/
```

It's the alignment you want but you have to put yourself the `*`, they are not added automatically anymore but the cursor will be aligned when you type Enter.